# Since and the perfect tense

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, time

I know that saying:

(A) *I **am** here since six o’clock.* or (B) *I **was** here since six o’clock*.

would sound unidiomatic because of using "since" and its requisite tense which is present perfect. For example:

(C) - *I **have been** here since six o’clock*.

But I came across another sentence somewhere in a textbook which caused me to doubt. Is it possible to say:

(D) - *I **had been** there since six o’clock*.

If yes, what's the semantic difference between "C" and "D", and when should I use each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your (D) is past perfect ... it refers to a time in the past just as (C) refers to a time in the present.

So (D) means that you were “there” from six o’clock to whatever past time you are talking about.

> When Amy finally arrived at the bar at eight o’clock I **had been** there since six o’clock.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a zillion Stoney. I got the point.